# How to fix image problems when streaming h.264 via gstreamer udpsink

Tags: linux, video-streaming, gstreamer, h.264

Using gstreamer I want to stream images from several Logitech C920 webcams to a Janus media server in RTP/h.264 format. The webcams produce h.264 encoded video streams, so I can send the streams to a UDP sink without re-encoding data, only payloading it.

I'm using the gst-interpipe plugin to switch between the different webcams, so that the video stream received by Janus stays the same, but with images coming from whatever webcam I choose.

It works but I'm experiencing some problems with broken frames where the colors are gray and details are blurred away, mainly the first 5 - 10 seconds after I switch between webcam source streams. After that the images correct themselves.

[First frames](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRIfW.png)

[After 5 - 10 seconds or more](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KITwG.png)

First I thought it was a gst-interpipe specific problem, but I can reproduce it by simply setting up two pipelines - one sending a video stream to a UDP sink and one reading from a UDP source:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v -e v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! queue ! video/x- 
h264,width=1280,height=720,framerate=30/1 ! rtph264pay 
config-interval=1 ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=8004


gst-launch-1.0 -v udpsrc port=8004 caps = "application/x-rtp, 
media=video, clock-rate=90000, encoding-name=H264, payload=96" ! 
rtph264depay ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! xvimagesink
```

NB: I'm not experiencing this problem if I send the video stream directly to an xvimagesink, i.e. when not using UDP streaming.

Am I missing some important parameters in my pipelines? Is this a buffering issue? I really have no idea how to correct this.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution to this problem? I've been experiencing similar issues streaming an H264 camera, and I've noticed similar gray glitches every few seconds, particularly when you turn on the lights quickly.

Comment: What solved my problem was to use uvch264src instead of v4l2src and then set initial-bitrate=3000000 average-bitrate=3000000 iframe-period=1000 (you can try to adjust these settings a little for your needs). Furthermore, I dumped gst-interpipe and used input-selector instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the nature of temporal dependencies of video streams you cannot just tune in into stream and expect it to be decode-able immediately. Correct decoding can only start at Random-Access-Point frames (e.g. I- or IDR-frames). before that you will get image data that rely on video frames you haven't received - so they will look broken. Some decoders offers some control on what to do on these cases. `libavdec_h264` for example has a `output-corrupt` option. (But actually I don't how it behaves for "correct" frames which just are missing reference frames). Or they may have options to skip everything until a RAP-frame occurs. This depends on your specific decoder implementation. Note however that on any of these options the initial delay before you will see any image will increase.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, Florian. So the broken frames I experience when I set up my udpsink + udpsrc example above are due to missing buffering of data - makes sense. I guess my switching scenario is different then, since gst-interpipe supposedly switches pipelines by using internal buffer transfer without data copying, including timestamp synchronization. The switch is occurring here: WebCam source -> Switch -> UDP Sink.

Comment: I don't know what gst-interpipe is about in detail - but when it comes to switching for H.264 (and other prediction based codecs) the logic on switching depends on the particular codec. That means somethings specific needs to be implemented for each individual codec which can be very complex. A generic approach probably will always end up in what you are seeing.